# Javascript Regex - Get first word after substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a URL like this:

"/parameterOne/parameterTwo/parameterThree/parameterFour/ParameterFive"

I want to firstly find the substring 'paramaterOne', then find the word immediately after this substring between the slashes which is 'paramterTwo'.

This is the RegEx I have written so far:

```
\parameterOne\b\/[^/]*[^/]*\/
```

It returns both 'parameterOne' and 'parameterTwo'. How can I modify this to only return 'parameterTwo' or is there a JavaScript solution that is better?

I do not want to find this parameter by index, it is important I have to find parameterOne first and then find parameterTwo immediately after.

Comment: `\/parameterOne\/([^\/]*)\/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\/parameterOne\b\/([^/]*[^/]*)\/
```

You can try this and grab the value of `group 1` or capture 1.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/99

```
var re = /\/parameterOne\b\/([^\/]*[^\/]*)\//gm;
var str = '/parameterOne/parameterTwo/parameterThree/parameterFour/ParameterFive';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}

or

var myString = "/parameterOne/parameterTwo/parameterThree/parameterFour/ParameterFive";
var myRegexp = /\/parameterOne\b\/([^\/]*[^\/]*)\//gm;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

Comment: This is returning parameterOne as well, it should only return parameterTwo

Comment: There’s still this `\p` which should be `\/p`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript `split` function.

Following code may be taken as example :

```
"/parameterOne/parameterTwo/parameterThree/parameterFour/ParameterFive".split("/")[2]
```